# Java: Mapping DTOs hierarchy using MapStruct

Tags: mapstruct, mapper

I have Pet, Dog and Cat entity classes. Dog and Cat classes extend Pet.

Also I have PetDTO, DogDTO and CatDTO annotated with @JsonSubtype so Jackson resolves well the class of the dtos.

I want to write a mapper using MapStruct that takes a PetDTO entity (can be a DogDTO or a CatDTO) and returns a Dog or a Cat.

For me in this case, the main goal of using a mapping library is to avoid awful code using instanceof.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: `I want to write a mapper using MapStruct that takes a PetDTO entity (can be a DogDTO or a CatDTO) and returns a Dog or a Cat.` - how do you imagine a signature of such function?

Comment: public Pet map(PetDTO){ ... }

Comment: why not map them in separate mapping methods? is there some specific business requirement behind this?

Comment: An endpoint in the controller layer receives a PetDTO. Because of metadata in @JsonSubtype, Jackson knows to map that into a DogDTO or a CatDTO. Suppose that I have that in variable "petDTO".Then I have to map that into the domain model invoking Pet pet = mapper.map(petDTO), so it must be a single method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible out-of-the-box - see this ticket in mapstruct's GitHub: [#366 Support for abstract class mapping or classes with base class](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/366). You can try to push it there or maybe contribute this feature yourself. Looks like a reasonable feature to ask for.

I guess that with the current state of affairs this is your best option:

```
@Mapper
public interface PetMapper {

    default PetDTO toPetDto(Pet pet) {
        if (pet instanceof Dog) {
            return toDogDTO((Dog) pet);
        }

        if (pet instanceof Cat) {
            return toCatDTO((Cat) pet);
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown subtype of Pet");
    }

    default Pet toPetEntity(PetDTO petDTO) {
        if (petDTO instanceof DogDTO) {
            return toDogEntity((DogDTO) petDTO);
        }

        if (petDTO instanceof CatDTO) {
            return toCatEntity((CatDTO) petDTO);
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown subtype of PetDTO");
    }

    DogDTO toDogDTO(Dog dog);
    Dog toDogEntity(DogDTO dogDTO);

    CatDTO toCatDTO(Cat cat);
    Cat toCatEntity(CatDTO catDTO);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up implementing a Mapper for a similar case as above was using a combination of a switch-type, with MapStruct Update Existing and creation Mappers.

In my case a property on the source object dictated the subclass we had to generate.
I initially had different mappers for each subtype, but the duplication of the common mapped properties just seemed wrong. So I came up with the following, leveraging the ability of MapStruct to use updating mappers in order to tackle the common parent type properties:

```java
import org.mapstruct.*;

@Mapper
@Named("QualifierPetMapper")
public interface PetMapper {
    @Named("DelegatingPetMapper")
    @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
    default PetTarget mapPet(PetSource petSource) {
        switch (petSource.getPetType()) {
            case "DOG":
                DogTarget dogTarget = mapDog(petSource);
                updatePet(dogTarget, petSource);
                return (dogTarget);

            case "CAT":
                CatTarget catTarget = mapCat(petSource);
                updatePet(catTarget, petSource);
                return (catTarget);

            default:
                throw new CustomException("Unsupported Pet type: "+ petSource.getPetType());

        }
    }

    @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
    // Specific mappings for Dog
    @Mapping(target = "dogfood.name", source = "dogfoodName")
    DogTarget mapDog(PetSource petSource);

    @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
    // Specific mappings for Cat
    @Mapping(target = "fish.name", source = "favoriteFish")
    CatTarget mapCat(PetSource petSource);

    @Named("RootPetMapper")
    @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
    // Common properties for Pet
    @Mapping(target = "weight.value", source = "weightValue")
    @Mapping(target = "name.value", source = "petName")
    @Mapping(target = "color", source = "mainColor")
    void updatePet(@MappingTarget PetTarget petTarget, PetSource petSource);
}
```